# insert big images…cut in two parts, LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I would like to know how can I cut a figure in a way that some part is show in one page and the continuation in other page. Actually it just take the all figure to the next page and I get a lots of space empty that really looks ugly. Thanks.

Comment: Splitting the figure is likely to look very bad (unless you're writing a book and you have a figure that goes across facing pages like in the FAQ answer Lev Bishop mentioned). Why don't you let the figure float?

Comment: This really can't be helpfully answered without a minimal example. Since that has not be added in 6 years, it seems unlikely to make an appearance now.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dpfloat) solve your problem? If not, please give more details about what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi Lev, i'm trying to put a figure that is too big for one page. In the beginning of the page i have an intro text and then the image, but the intro isn't too big, so the empty space in the page is just too large. My idea is that automatically show a part of the figure in the intro page and the left part in the next page.

Comment: Like i say in the question right now the entire figure is moved to the next page. Also the figure is so big that the caption part is out of margin, so spliting the figure in two parts will be a good solution. One alternative is that I manually split the figure in two parts but i hope that exists an automatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to `trim` and `clip` an image vertically, spreading it over two pages at exactly the point needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\vfill

\noindent
\adjustbox{trim=0pt {\dimexpr\height-9\baselineskip} 0pt 0pt, clip}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\noindent
\adjustbox{trim=0pt 0pt 0pt 9\baselineskip, clip}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

The above image is split at 9 lines from the top with a possible `\vfill` before it (to make up for any incomplete text blocks).

Related: [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23860/5764)