# How to put one big image on each page

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, book-design, double-sided

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right)

The problem is the following:

I am formatting a twopage book on latex and I have a gantt diagram divided on two page size images.

What can I do for putting the first image on an even page and the second on the following page so that way one can open that pages and wiew the whole diagram without passing pages?

I tried using the following command before the two pictures, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
\newcommand{\newevenside}{
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{\newpage}{
    \newpage
    \phantom{placeholder} % doesn't appear on page
    \thispagestyle{empty} % if want no header/footer
    \newpage
    }
}
```

The code which I use for putting the images on the document is

```
\newevenside

\begin{figure}[hp!]
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{figuras/project1.eps}
\end{flushright}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hp!]
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{figuras/project2.eps}
\caption{O plan temporal do proxecto.\label{project}}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please take a look at the question that I have suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: No, that doesn't work for me, because I am not using `memoir` and I have two images on eps. Thanks, but that's not what I am searching for.

Comment: Take a second look -- Martin's answer doesn't use `memoir`, too.