# Two pictures, side by side on even and odd page

Tags: graphics, floats, double-sided, book-design

I am formatting a twopage book on latex and I have a diagram divided on two almost page size images. (Two captions).

What can I do for putting the first image on an even page and the second on the following page so that way one can open that pages and wiew the whole diagram without passing pages? The two parts of the diagram are in two different files, as opposed to the post ["How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right). In other words, I would like the same as the above post, but just much less functionality, such as dividing the picture into wo parts automatically and such. It would be nice, if the picture waits to be outputted until the next even side begins.

I tried using the following command before the two pictures, but that doesn't seem to work, cf. [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tips_and_Tricks#New_even_page).

```
\newcommand{\newevenside}{
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{\newpage}{
    \newpage
    \phantom{placeholder} % doesn't appear on page
    \thispagestyle{empty} % if want no header/footer
    \newpage
    }
}
```

The problem is that it would place both figures on the left side, two different doublepages.

The code which I use for putting the images on the document is

```
\newevenside

\begin{figure}[hp!]
\includegraphics[width=18cm,angle=90]{figuras/project1.eps}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{fig:gantt1}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[hp!]
\includegraphics[width=18cm,angle=90]{figuras/project2.eps}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{fig:gantt}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you sure the images (and their captions) fit within the text block boundary? It there is any chance it doesn't, placing it on any specific page will not work.

Comment: Also, don't re-edit older posts that have been marked as a duplicate in order to draw more attention. If you think the question has not been answered in full, or is perhaps not a duplicate, discuss this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) with a moderator (or others) and vote to re-open. Almost word-for-word this question matches the unaltered version of [How to put one big image on each page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26958/5764), yet you don't reference it as a [follow-up questions](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using **dpfloat** package. 
The example below is self-explanatory

```
\usepackage{dpfloat}

\begin{figure} % first part of the pic
    \begin{leftfullpage} % this part will be put on the LEFT page
    \includegraphics{...}
    \end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % second part of the pic
    \begin{fullpage}% this part will be put on the RIGHT page
    \includegraphics{...}
    \end{fullpage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Awesome, this one worked fantastically!
 It is important to have no `[!htbp]` or anyother "placemarker" in after the `\begin{figure}` command! 
Do you think, this could be used for solving [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108440/insert-a3-page-with-figure-into-a4-document-with-active-references) too?

Comment: What concerns your other question, I do not think dpfloat is relevant there.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is best not to allow them to float then they will stay together just use

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
```

then

```
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\mbox{}\clearpage\fi
\includegraphhics{project1}
\captionof{figure}{...}
\clearpage
\includegraphhics{project2}
\captionof{figure}{...}
\clearpage
```

It's best not to use the `.eps` extension in `\includegraphics`:  makes it easier to switch between latex and pdflatex. Not relevant as I've removed the float but `[hp!]`
prevents `t` floats which is a bit strange given that `h` floats are allowed.