# Template for a book for children

Tags: templates, book-design

I intend to (write and) typeset in LaTeX one or more books for my almost-4 child. They would be books telling a fairy tale (or the labours of Hercules, say) with one sentence and a large illustration in each page. Assuming to have the text and the (probably jpeg) illustration, do you know a package / template / set of macros to put everything together in an easy and pleasant way? "Pleasant" means here, for instance, that the text might be in a different position in each page, or in one or several lines, and so on.

Comment: My initial thoughts were as follows.  For each "page" we use two macros to set the text and the image.  Then we have a family of basic templates which use these two (sort of how `\maketitle` works with the title and author).  I would probably use TikZ to make the templates since it gives easy access to absolute and relative positioning on the page.  So on each page you'd have `\text{Hercules strangled the snakes} \image{HerculesAndSnakes.jpg} \usepagetemplate{text under picture}`.  I certainly don't know of a package already in existence for this, but it wouldn't be hard to make one if not.

Comment: I would also suggest using this style for some pictures (even if it is only one), depending on your document layout as well as the images: [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23860/5764)

Answer (score 32):

Children's books are as unique as the children that read them. They are very individualistic and would be very difficult to fit them in a *class*. Each book deserves its own.

Here is a draft for one (very rough, but just to illustrate that it is not that hard to develop a special template),

[image]  [image]
[image][image]

and here is the code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\frenchspacing
\newfont{\HUGE}{cmr17 at 96pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{3.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{5.125in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.375in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.125in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.25in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5\parindent}
\ifpdf
  \pdfpageheight 7.5in 
  \pdfpagewidth 4.625in
\else
%\setlength{\paperheight}{7.5in}
%\setlength{\paperwidth}{4.625in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{1.9375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{1.9375in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{1.75in}
\fi
\newcommand{\hstroke}{\rule[0.5ex]{5.0em}{0.2ex}}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.0em}%
\begin{picture}(45,16)(0,0)
\put(-0.625,0){\framebox(6.2,7.25){\HUGE \textcolor{purple}{A}}}
\put(5.875,5.625){\parbox[t]{15em}{\Huge \noindent LITTLE GIFT\linebreak
\raggedright FOR LITTLE\linebreak
FEET\linebreak
}}
\end{picture}
\hspace*{-0.6em}\rule{1.08\textwidth}{0.3ex}\\
{\small \sc by}\\
{\small YIANNIS LAZARIDES}\\
{\footnotesize Author of ``Myths of TeX''}\\
\vspace*{18.5 ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3ex}\\
{\small
DOHA\phantom{ZZZZZ,}\hfill\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\bullet$}\hfill THE CAMEL\linebreak
QATAR\hfill\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\bullet$}\hfill PRESS
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{18ex}
\begin{center}
{\em Copyright, $\mit 2011$}\\
{\sc By the Little Girl \& Company}\\
\hstroke\\
{\em All rights reserved}\\
\vspace*{18ex}
{\sc A little story book}\\
{\sc for a little girl}\\
\vspace*{12ex}
Made in the wild.
\end{center}
\newpage
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{20ex}
\begin{center}
                           {\scriptsize FOR}\\
                {\large \bf Li, Mary and John}\\
\smallskip
                   {\footnotesize AND THE REST\\
                     OF THE WORLD'S\\
                    CHILDREN}
\end{center}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\mainmatter


\chapter*{Stories of Greece}
\Large

Once upon a time there were two girls. One of them lived in Greece and the other on lived on the land of the Moon \ldots

\pagebreak

\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{children-0}

\ldots and there was a time when everyone was dressed in white\ldots


\hskip-1in\includegraphics[width=1.43\textwidth]{children-01}

\ldots and the gods had wings and there were no demons \ldots
\par

\pagebreak

\hskip-.5in\includegraphics[width=1.43\textwidth]{children-03}

\bigskip

\ldots and on the other side of the world in the Land of the Moon Wi Li was sleeping \ldots
\end{document}
```

You can view the pdf at [crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com/Ngftpy2).

... and I think the books should be small to fit on small laps and to be easy for little fingers to flip the pages...

Answer (score 7):

Would the beamer class help you already?
You could create it as a presentation and print it. Each page (foil) gets a picture, the text is already big.

A quick example (needs a `picture`).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
%<<theme>>
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\title{Fairytale}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Fairytale}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\framePicFull}[1]{
    \def\beamertoolgraphic{\includegraphicsJustified{#1}}
    \@framePicHorizontal
}%\framePicFull
\newcommand{\@framePicHorizontal}[2][beamertooldummy]{
\centering
\ifthenelse{\equal{beamertooldummy}{#1}}{
    \beamertoolgraphic
}{
    \hyperlink{#1}{\beamertoolgraphic}
}\\\noindent #2
}%\framePicHorizontal
\newlength{\breit}
\newlength{\hoch}
\newcommand\includegraphicsJustified[1]{%
    \settowidth{\breit}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
    \settoheight{\hoch}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\hoch > \textheight}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\breit > \linewidth}}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{#1}%
        }{
            \includegraphics[height=0.9\textheight]{#1}%
        }%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\breit > \linewidth}}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{#1}%
        }{%
            \includegraphics[]{#1}%
        }%
    }%
}

\makeatother
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{My Fairytale}
\framePicFull{Picture}{Once upon \ldots}
}


\end{document}
```

The example stretch the picture to nearly fullpage. Depending on our pictures you should use other settings. Best your picture have already the correct size and you use just `\includegraphicx`.

You could define (or search) a nice template with ornaments or something similar.