# How to make a photo album for my child by LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, graphics

I am planning to make a photo album by latex for my child's birthday, but I cannot find some suitable latex template, as a TeX fan, I want to make this gift special. Could anyone let me know how to make it?

Thank you guys so much in advance.

There are some example pics I found which are very close to what I want.

[image: The album cover]
[image: Inside page example]

The editors may concerning about this is a duplicate problem, and they also give me some links below:

You may get ideas from tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759, tex.stackexchange.com/a/31266, tex.stackexchange.com/a/33296, and tex.stackexchange.com/a/45120

However, my problem for this including fonts, background, and also the frame in a page by tikz(or other packages), I want to put pictures and corresponding captions into a page by 1*2, 2*1, 2*2, 3*3, etc. I've looking for the solution by a period of time, but no one satisfied me. I intend to use all the nice pictures and compile them into a nice book by latex, and then print it out as a hardcover.

Thanks again.

Comment: This question will likely be closed because it is primarily opinion based what a suitable template for this purpose is. You need to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve and what is causing you trouble. You also need to show what you have tried with a MWE.

Comment: You may get ideas from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31266/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33296/, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45120/