# How to achieve a few different page layouts for a photobook?

Tags: layout, photobook

I'm considering designing a photobook in LaTeX but am concerned that I will run into unanticipated problems, so wanted to give some details and see how these might be achievable. My idea for this book:

- square pages, e.g. 8.5 x 8.5, with bleed area
- a few different layouts

  - page-width landscape image, with text below
  - page-length portrait image, with text on the outside
  - dual-page landscape image, spans page length, fills the left and a portion of the right page, with text on the right page
  - above, but with dual-page landscape image flush to the right instead of left
- About a paragraph of text per image, but will not overflow onto next page

I've already read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33290/two-column-latex-class-for-a-photobook) some concerns for using floats. How might I approach such a LaTeX project, e.g. what class should I start with and how do I go about wrangling LaTeX into these layouts? Or, is LaTeX not really the right tool for this job and I'm better off going to something like [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/)? I would prefer LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure TeX is the right tool for this. If you will print the book, then there might be specific photo book creating "applications" at the website you buy from. I haven't tried them out, but I think they are just meant to do the kind of setup you want.

Nevertheless, if you want to do it with LaTeX, I think that you might go for using tikz with some background mechanism. I don't know the details, but I'm sure someone will point you in the right direction.

Meanwhile, I did more or less what you wanted, but using layers in [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/). I used photos having proportion 2:3 (or 3:2). The `\dontleavehmode` are just there not to have "empty pages" except for the layers. In the first version I placed the text with layers, but after sleeping, I think I prefer to put the text on an ordinary page. Perhaps less flexible, but probably simpler.

Code and (two) images of the output follows. The file was compiled with `context`. I hope it will help somehow. Good luck!

```
\definepapersize[photobook][
    width=8.5in,
    height=8.5in,
]
\setuppapersize[photobook]

\setupalign[flushleft,verytolerant]

\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond]

\setuppagenumbering[
    alternative=doublesided,
    state=stop,
]

\setuplayout[
    backspace=0.5in,
    topspace=0.5in,
    margin=0in,
    width=fit,
    height=fit,
    header=0in,
    footer=0in,
    alternative=middle,
]

\definelayout[photopage][
    backspace=6in,
    width=2in,
]



\definelayer[portrait][
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
    doublesided=yes,
]

\definelayer[landscape][
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
    doublesided=yes,
]

\definelayer[doublebackground][
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
    doublesided=yes,
]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={doublebackground,portrait,landscape}]

\starttexdefinition LeftPoirtrait #1
\setlayer[portrait][left][
    corner={right,top},
    location={left,bottom},
    ]{#1}
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition RightPoirtrait #1
\setlayer[portrait][right]{#1}
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition LandScape #1
\setlayer[landscape]{#1}
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition LeftDouble #1
\setlayer[doublebackground][left]{\externalfigure[#1][width=1.5\paperwidth]}
\setlayer[doublebackground][right][
    x=0.5\paperwidth,
    y=0in,
    corner={right,top},
    location={left,bottom},
    ]{\externalfigure[#1][width=1.5\paperwidth]}
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition RightDouble #1
\setlayer[doublebackground][left][
    x=0.5\paperwidth,y=0in,
    location={right,bottom},
    corner={left,top},
    ]{\externalfigure[#1][width=1.5\paperwidth]}
\setlayer[doublebackground][right][
    x=\paperwidth,
    y=0in,
    location={left,bottom},
    corner={left,top},
    ]{\externalfigure[#1][width=1.5\paperwidth]}
\stoptexdefinition


\starttext
\start
\switchtobodyfont[130pt]

\leftaligned{The}
\midaligned{Photo}
\rightaligned{Book}
\stop

\page[even]
\setuplayout[photopage]

\LeftPoirtrait{\externalfigure[MX033-30.jpg][height=\paperheight]}
\samplefile{ward}
\page[yes]
\RightPoirtrait{\externalfigure[MX023-20.jpg][height=\paperheight]}
\dontleavehmode
\vfill
\samplefile{ward}

\page[even]

\LandScape{\externalfigure[autumn.jpg][width=\paperwidth]}
\dontleavehmode
\vfill
\samplefile{ward}

\page[yes]

\LandScape{\externalfigure[matematiker.jpg][width=\paperwidth]}
\dontleavehmode
\vfill
\samplefile{ward}

\page[even]

\LeftDouble{shark.jpg}
\dontleavehmode
\page[yes]
\dontleavehmode
\samplefile{knuth}

\page[even]

\RightDouble{hund.jpg}
\samplefile{knuth}

\page[even]
\setuplayout[reset]
\start
\switchtobodyfont[130pt]

\leftaligned{This is}
\rightaligned{the end}
\stop

\stoptext
```

[image: the first pages]
[image: the last pages]