# Template that follows this book layout

Tags: templates, document-classes

Is there a template out there with a format such as:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Template for a book for children](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31196/template-for-a-book-for-children)?  As they start out with, this is a hard thing to have a general solution to.  What aspects of this story/format are you looking to replicate?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if a template exists elsewhere, but you can easily provide the required settings:

```
\documentclass[14pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a6paper,textheight=19\baselineskip,footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% kust to generate text for the example

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{193,158,88}
\definecolor{pagecolor}{RGB}{251,234,214}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\bfseries\filcenter\color{myorange}}{}{0em}{}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead{}{}{}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\linespread{2}
\raggedright
\pagecolor{pagecolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cookies}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{taf}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remarks about the class and packages used:

- [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir): Just because it gives `14pt` font size easily.
- [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec): change of the format for chapter titles. I used the `pagestyles` option to easily define the headers/footers. Using `titlesec` in this case (with `memoir`) won't have any undesired consequences.
- [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry): page layout.
- [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry): color settings for chapter titles and page background.
- [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx): image inclusion.