# Typeset book for children

Tags: graphics, memoir

I am working (writing and typesetting) on a book for children. I have used the memoir class. The book looks good for an adult audience. But I had ideas of making it more interesting for the children.

More specifically, how about adding little thumbnails to the table of contents page? These will be tiny images placed randomly and rotated randomly.

Or a different pattern border around each page? Like bright colored zigzag pattern for one page and may be, colored crayon strips on another?

With my limited experience and expertise in latex, I could not crack this one.

Any ideas/ suggestions/ solutions?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/13304) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Some other ideas not far away: [Cute Document in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-document-in-latex/63759#63759) and [Template for a book for children](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31196/template-for-a-book-for-children)

Comment: If you want help with the two particular ideas you mention, I think it would be better to have them in one question each, where you show us how far you have come. In the general brainstorming around what to do I would like to point out making the text easier to read, for example by increasing the leading. See http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/situational-typography/typography-for-children for some tips about fonts and such.

Comment: With this approach, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831, you could arbitrarily add things like images, borders, etc. to any page, without disturbing the underlying TeX formatting.