# How do I make a figure that spans a spread of two pages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, two-column, double-sided

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right)

I have a huge TikZ graphic inside a `figure` environment. I would like it to cover a spread so that the figure is cut in half, and the left half goes on an even (left-hand) page and the right half goes on the next (odd/right-hand) page. I want the regular page margins to apply, and all the rest of the document layout, too. I need to use the IEEE two-column paper format.

I know I could just manually remake the TikZ graphic into two parts and place each part in a new `figure` environment, and then resort to trickery to force the figures onto the pages I want. But it would be much cleaner and easier to update the graphic if I could make it independently of how it is positioned on the page. Also, if I decide to replace the TikZ graphic with, say, an EPS or PDF (or encounter the same issue another time when I have such an image), I'd like the solution to be independent of what I happen to have inside the `figure`.

So, how can I make a `figure` that spans a spread of two pages?

Comment: @PeterGrill: That certainly looks like it could do the trick. I have to try it out.

Comment: @PeterGrill: After checking out the question you proposed, I'm thinking this is a bit different because in this case, I'm actually generating the graphic with TikZ while the question deals only with spanning pre-generated image files over two pages.

Comment: Even though it may seem trivial, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the solution I posted for [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right) and then exchange any `\includegraphics[<options>]{<image file>}` with `\adjustbox{<some options>}{<your tikzpicture or similar>}` from the `adjustbox` package instead. It builds on the option keys provided by `graphicx` and is fully compatible with it, but applies them to text or picture environments instead of graphicx.

What you basically have to do is:

Split the `tikzpicture` using `\clipbox` or `\adjustbox{clip=...}` from the `adjustbox` package. You need to insert it twice and clip first the left part and then the right part. For this you should store the image first into a box register and then use the register twice. Even better, use my `storebox` package and the `\storebox\mystore{<your image>}` and `\usestorebox` macro which only stores the whole picture once in the PDF, while `\savebox` / `\usebox` stores it twice. I actually already wrote a `\splitbox` macro as part of `adjustbox` for this kind of thing, but it isn't released yet.

The `figure` environment makes things a little more tricky. You need to make sure that both are either on top or bottom and do not fall on one figure-only page which will happen if you don't have enough text around it.

---

Here the code from [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right) modified for picture environments. If you use several of these close to each other you need to use different box registers to hold them.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[disable]{storebox}
\newstorebox\twopagestorebox

% For the `memoir` class remove the following two packages.
% This class already provide the functionality of both
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%%%

\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.99}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.99}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.01}


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{twopagepicture}[3]{%
    \def\@dotwopagepicture{\@twopagepicture{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    \begin{storebox}{\twopagestorebox}%
}{%
    \end{storebox}%
    \ifstorebox
        \global\let\twopagestorebox=\twopagestorebox
    \else
        \global\setbox\twopagestorebox=\box\twopagestorebox
    \fi
    \@dotwopagepicture{\usestorebox\twopagestorebox}%
}

\newcommand*{\@twopagepicture}[4]{%
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
        \expandafter\@firstofone
    \else
        \expandafter\afterpage
    \fi
    {\afterpage{%
    \if #1t%
        \if #2p%
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        \if #2p%
            \if #1t%
                \vspace*{-\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}%
            \fi
        \fi
        \if #1b%
            \caption{#3}%
        \fi
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
        \if #2p\relax
            \let\mywidth\paperwidth
            \hskip-\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin\relax
        \else
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \fi
        \adjustbox{width=2\mywidth,Clip=0 0 {\mywidth} 0}{#4}}%
        \if #1b\else
            \caption{#3}%
        \fi
        \if #2p%
            \if #1b%
                \vspace*{-\dimexpr\paperheight-\textheight-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep\relax}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        \if #2p%
            \if #1t%
                \vspace*{-\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}%
            \fi
        \fi
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
        \if #2p%
            \let\mywidth\paperwidth
            \hskip-\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin\relax
        \else
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \fi
        \adjustbox{width=2\mywidth,Clip={\mywidth} 0 0 0}{#4}}%
        \if #2p%
            \if #1b%
                \vspace*{-\dimexpr\paperheight-\textheight-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep\relax}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \end{figure}%
    }}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{twopagepicture}{b}{l}{Test}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2\linewidth,10);
    \draw (0,10) -- (2\linewidth,0);
    \draw (\linewidth,5) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{twopagepicture}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]

Note that there is a bug in the current version of `storebox` (v1.0) caused by the update of `collectbox`. I already fixed it and uploaded v1.1 to CTAN. Please remove the `disabled` option from it once you have the new version. So far it runs in fallback mode and actually uses saveboxes instead.