# Scale image to page width?

Tags: graphics, scaling

I use

```
\inclugraphics[scale=TRYING TO GUESS THE NUMBER FOR PAGE WIDTH]{...}
```

but I find this errorsome, is there some ready flag to set the image to page width? I usually use PNG and JPG photos.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`

Comment: Simply use `width=\textwidth` to scale it to the width of the text area, as egreg already noted. (The whole page would be `\paperwidth` and would cause an overfull error.) You should have a look at the [Graphic Guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) for all the possible options for `\includegraphics`. Also check the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package which adds several more options to it.

Comment: Similar question in SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707934/determine-text-width-in-latex), contacted mod to look for this. Perhaps merging?

Comment: When the idea is to fit the images to the margins, it is better to get used to use `\linewidth` ("only the actual width of the  lines") that `\textwidth` ("the whole width of the text area").  In one column text both lengths will be same thing,  but inside a nested list, or in two column text, or a tabular with a `p{3cm}` column, for instance, `\linewidth` still is the correct length, whereas `\textwidth`  will produce here only junk results.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Use `\textwidth` for the width of the text block, and `\paperwidth` if you want to fit it into the paper width. You could also use `\linewidth` if you want to fit the image within the line width, which may vary depending on the environment you're in (for example, within a list like `enumerate`).

Note that if you use `\includegraphics` outside a `figure` or `table` environment, you might want to prepend it with `\noindent` to avoid the image being pushed over to the right by `\parindent`. Also, centering the image within the page width (when using `\paperwidth`) is best obtained using

```
\begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{...}}
\end{center}
```

or

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{...}}
```

In both instances it typesets a box of width `\textwidth`, while the contents may stretch outside this width (given by `width=\paperwidth`). Fixing it to `\textwidth` avoids `Overfull \hbox warnings`.

This works as expected within the `article` and `report` document class, while some horizontal re-adjustment is required in `book`. For completeness, and without resorting to page numbering issues that may occur at shipout if the image is placed near a page break, the following `\centerimg[<options>]{<image>}` command works for all standard document classes, including `book`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,changepage}

\newcommand{\adjustimg}{% Horizontal adjustment of image
  \checkoddpage%
  \ifoddpage\hspace*{\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\else\hspace*{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\centerimg}[2][width=\textwidth]{% Center an image
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\adjustimg\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\mbox{} \par
\noindent\centerimg[width=\paperwidth,height=200pt]{tiger}

\newpage

\mbox{} \par
\noindent\centerimg[width=\paperwidth,height=200pt]{tiger}
\end{document}
```

The horizontal adjustment for `book` (obtained via `\adjustimg`) depends on whether the page number is odd or even. The above MWE, with the [`tiger` image](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/lgc2/pstricks/tiger.eps), compiles to the output:

[image]

Comment: I don't think the `\paperwidth` works other than in the article class, provided no change is made to the pagination parameters.

Comment: Better would be `\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{...}}` (see [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth/16584#16584)) or `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,center]{...}` with `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`.

Comment: @egreg: I'm using it with success in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right/23865#23865 and it works with `memoir` as well.

Comment: @egreg: Do you know the horizontal length causing the difference in `book`?

Comment: It depends on whether the page is odd or even: `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`. Look at package `layout` for getting a nice drawing. However the problem is to know what's the page number!

Comment: @Werner The horizontal difference will depend on the class. You need to start from `paperwidth` and start subtracting. In book from memory there is a 0.4 of an inch correction.

Comment: Using \paperwidth doesn't work indeed, as the image is still placed where the text should begin and not at the left margin of page.

Comment: @Ariel: Are you using `book` or `report`? Did you see the horizontal adjustment `\adjustimg`?

Comment: @Werner, indeed I use `report`. I solved it indeed with the `\makebox` suggested by @Martin.

Answer (score 51):

This worked for me

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Normal_Case_1_req_1_response}
      \caption{Normal Case: 1 Request \& 1 Response.}
       \label{normal_case}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `figure` is a float and is therefore not directly typeset inside the current environment, but rather floats to the next best position. Therefore putting it into a `center` environment doesn't make sense and doesn't result in a centered image. For this the `\centering` macro is used *inside* `figure` as you also did.

Answer (score 27):

I used `pdfpages` package to include a `png`. Simple and effective. Fills the entire page with the graphic.

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
...
\includepdf{image.png}
```

Happy `TeX`ing!

Comment: Seeing as pdfpages supports .png and .jpg as well as .pdf-files this is the easiest way to achieve what OP was trying to do. There's also the possibility to specify optional scale arguments as used with includegraphics.

Comment: Thanks! By far the easiest way possible... Didn't know that it also supports images :)

Answer (score 18):

`width=\columnwidth` worked for me in a two-column document:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{myfigure.pdf}
    \caption{My amazing figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: First one of the answers that worked for me in a minipage / figure, thanks!

Comment: Works pretty well with pdfLaTeX, too, with a .png figure.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should work with the `easyfig` package from Martin Scharrer : [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easyfig.).

Or, maybe, look at this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53497/how-do-i-get-the-exact-dimension-of-a-picture-in-latex) post where I've ask a similar question (I think at least).

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{example.png}}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{LABEL}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image to be automatically scaled to fit *both* vertically and horizontally while maintaining proportions, this works.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{image.jpg}
}
```