# Define the size of an imported picture

Tags: graphics, scaling

Is it possible to use the width of the paper as a variable in order to set the width of an imported graphics? For instance when I want the picture size to be the width of the paper, minus 3 centimeters, or half of the paper's width etc.

Comment: Yes, there is, and you're probably referring to the width of the text block, not the paper width. Using the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc), you can do all kinds of length calculations. I think the following is a duplicate: [Scale image to page width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39147/5764) Does it help? Using the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (and `calc`), you can use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-3cm]{image}` or `\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image}`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simply to use `\textwidth` and do whatever you want with it. Of course by width of paper you mean the text block width, not the paper itself, in that case you use `\paperwidth`.

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-5cm]{./Images/MyImage}
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{./Images/MyImage}
\includegraphics[width=2\textheight]{./Images/MyImage}
\includegraphics[height=\marginparwidth]{./Images/MyImage}
```

you could use `pt` or `inch` or `em` ...etc, instead of `cm`.

Refer to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions for useful page dimensions commands.