# Inserted Picture Position & Picture Size

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am a newbie in LaTeX. I am currently using it writing a very simple school lab report. I encounter a problem when I try to enlarge the inserted pictures by changing the

```
[width=6.0in]
```

parameter in

```
The graph now becomes Figure~\ref{pmos_gamma}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.0in]{pmos_gamma}
    \caption{$V_{BS}=0.1V, 0.3V, 0.5V, 0.7V$}
    \label{pmos_gamma}
\end{figure}
```

I cannot know the maximum size of a picture that will not make itself "pushed" to the next page. If the picture is too big, as we know it will be pushed down to next page. I don't wish that to happen.

**So how can I ensure the picture will  NOT be pushed to the next page while I am trying to enlarge the picture?**

(Position highest priority. Under that the picture should be as large as possible.)

**Update:**

**Adopting the `\MyFig{}{}{}` solution, the following code snippet**

```
\title{blabla}
\author{
blabla
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{capt-of}
\linespread{1.25}

\newcommand\MyFig[3]{%
    \par\medskip\noindent%
    \setbox0=\vbox{\captionof{figure}{#1}}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[%
        height=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\abovecaptionskip-\ht0-1\bigskipamount-\medskipamount\relax,
        width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}
    \captionof{figure}{#2}
    \label{#3}%
    \end{minipage}\par\bigskip%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
blabla
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
blabla

\paragraph{Outline}
blabla

\section{Task 1}\label{task1}
\paragraph{2.1 $V_{t0}$}
After the circuit has been set up in \textit{LTSpice} as instructed, the simulations were run. The family of $I-V$ curves generated are shown in Figure~\ref{nmosfigure}.
\MyFig{task1_nmos}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}

\end{document}
```

**produces the following errors:**

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.47 ...s}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\sbox ...hbox {\color@setgroup #2\color@endgroup }
l.47 ...s}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.47 ...s}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.47 ...s}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! I can't write on file `report.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...stobj \GPT@objref }}}\fi \pdfximage
\GPT@RuleAttr \ifx \GPT@pa...
l.47 ...s}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1654 strings out of 494045
22800 string characters out of 3148364
80363 words of memory out of 3000000
4970 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
9456 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
27i,6n,32p,370b,199s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

`Line 47` **is** `\MyFig{task1_nmos}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

Now the caption is previously boxed, its height measured and then taken into account automatically; the syntax for `\MyFig` is simply

```
\MyFig{<image file>}{<caption>}{<label>}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newcommand\MyFig[3]{%
\par\medskip\noindent%
\setbox0=\vbox{\captionof{figure}{#2}}%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[%
  height=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\abovecaptionskip-\ht0-1\bigskipamount-\medskipamount\relax,
  width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}
\captionof{figure}{#2}
\label{#3}%
\end{minipage}\par\bigskip%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\MyFig{example-image-a}{adasf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf}{fig:testa}

\lipsum[1]

\MyFig{example-image-b}{adasf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgsdg sdfgsf sadgs}{fig:testb}

\lipsum[1-5]

\MyFig{example-image-c}{adasf sadgsdg sdfgsf}{fig:testc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\MyFig` scales the figure accordingly to the available space on the page. It uses a `minipage` and `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package to provide a caption.

Comment: But that still needs the caption to be manually adjusted? Does it? If that is what you meant by, taking care of the caption height.

Comment: Thanks! It seems promising. As a newbie, I find it even difficult to apply this to my code. May I ask whether you could apply this to my code given in the question? Just one demo on my code will do. Thanks!

Comment: @MMA you need to give as optional argument the number of lines spanned by the caption.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng my example code shows how to use the macro. Copy the definition of \MyFig in the preamble of your document and then, instead of `\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pmos_gamma}
    \caption{$V_{BS}=0.1V, 0.3V, 0.5V, 0.7V$}
    \label{pmos_gamma}
\end{figure}` simply use `\MyFig{pmos_gamma}{$V_{BS}=0.1V, 0.3V, 0.5V, 0.7V$}{pmos_gamma}` (no need for the optional argument here, since the caption only spans one line).

Comment: @MMA now, in my updated answer, no manual calculations are needed.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng please see my updated answer, now the calculations are done automatically.

Comment: Thanks almost fixed. But I encountered errors... `\MyFig{task1_nmos}{NMOS $I_{DS}$ vs. $V_{DS}$}{nmosfigure}`

Comment: @perfectionm1ng saying just that is useless. What exactly is the error message that you get? What is the code producing this error? Please edit your question and add there a *minimal*, complete document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  Thanks for the advice. Please see edited question. :)

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Yes, I had a little mistake in my code. Sorry about that. I've fixed it in my updated answer. Please use the updated definition of `\MyFig` and there should be no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you modify your code like this so that the width of the picture is dependent on text width?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pmos_gamma}
    \caption{$V_{BS}=0.1V, 0.3V, 0.5V, 0.7V$}
    \label{pmos_gamma}
\end{figure}
```

If you still get some overfull message and/or unwanted situation you will want to modify the width to something like `width=0.9\textwidth`.

The above answer is applicable if your picture is more of a landscape nature *(wider than longer)*. If your picture is more of portrait nature, then something like `\includegraphics[width=\textheight]{pmos_gamma}` or `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textheight]{pmos_gamma}` will be applicable.

Please tweak a bit with the parameters to get the best results.

Of course, you can write a macro to measure the dimensions beforehand and then use some kind of if-then to dynamically apply the dimensions. But that will more of an overkill, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it helps a bit. But I still have to adjust the width=\textwidth so as to keep all the pictures in position right? E.g. some big pictures maybe 0.5\textwidth. small ones \textwidth will do. Can I somewhat fix the locations first, and then enlarge the pic to its max?

Comment: If you mean placing at your desired/intended location by "fix the locations first", then perhaps you can use the [float package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float) and use [H] as placement speciﬁer. And please see the end part of my post about writing a macro to dynamically adjust the width. As my experience goes over these years, I attempted that many times, only to give up finding that there is just one more special case to handle. Also please see [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39147/scale-image-to-page-width) for other relevant discussions.