# The inserted image is too big

Tags: graphics

I am using the `\includegraphics` feature of LaTeX to insert an image in my document but it is so big that it only shows a part of it. What do I need to do?

I know it is not due to the scale as I have scaled to a tenth using `[scale=..]` but it has not changed.

I tried to save it as pdf and changed rasterizing and margin numbers but it has not worked. But I maybe doing it wrong.

Comment: Try google "includegraphics scale to fit", and you will find eg. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39147/scale-image-to-page-width

Answer (score 7):

Please provide a minimal working example when you ask questions. In this case, though, you can just use one of the options provided by `graphicx` for resizing images.

For example,

```
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
```

if it is too wide or

```
\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-b}
```

if it is too high or

```
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=.25\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
```

if you aren't sure which.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 lines just does the wonder of including the image just into the article size.!

```latex
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{<image>}
```