# Images on multiple pages

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right)

I need to insert a really big diagram and i need to split it in two pages. Is it supported in any way? If not, how can i be sure the two pages will be perfectly aligned and that they will be printed in facing pages? Is there any kind of template?

Comment: Something like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right/23865#23865

Comment: Yeah thank you, i will take a look, probably it will work