# How do I make figure captions span multiple pages?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, captions

How do I make figure captions span multiple pages?

I have a very long caption for a figure and would like it to carry on to the next page.

EDIT: I would like this to work in both one sided and two sided modes

Comment: There is no easy default way to do it, but it might be possible with some trickery. You are talking about a two-sided document where the caption starts on the left page and goes onto the right one, do you? Kind of reminds me on [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/23865#23865,) while that question was more about the figure. You can also have multi-line captions.

Comment: oh dear! that seems to imply a massive effort. Thinking I'll just move my caption into the text body :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a floating environment which can't handle page breaks you can use a simple list environment. To set a caption you can use the command `\captionof`. The command is provided by

- the package [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of),
- the package [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) or
- a [KOMA-Class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) `scrreprt`, `scrbook` and `scrartcl`

Here an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{center}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}

\captionof{figure}[short caption]{%
\kant[4-6]}
\end{center}

\noindent\hrulefill

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am able to compile your example, but lengthening the caption further (e.g., by changing `\kant[4-6]` to `\kant[3-6]`) results in a `! Dimension too large` error.  Do you know of a solution?

Comment: Tthis solution does not work as expected if you use the `caption` package or the `scrartcl` class: the page break is always between the figure and the caption, and not inside the caption itself.

Answer (score 6):

Well, @Marco Daniel answer did not work for me.

Searching google, though, I found this thread with the same issue (I reproduce the working code below):
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5881&f=45

The working answer to the thread is here:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5881&f=45#p22785

Only to clarify, in this thread one wants to use subfigures in the same figure, using package `subfig`. However, it also worked for me when skipping all the `subfig` related features.

By the way, I am not using any latex standard `documentclass`. I am using `elsarticle` documentclass, in which the package `caption` also worked fine.

Enjoy.

CODE (replace `<YOUR FIGURE>`, `<YOUR CAPTION>` and `<FIGURE LABEL>` with the file name, figure caption and figure label, respectively):

```
\documentclass{article}

%...

\usepackage{caption}
% the following format will be used to emulate the captions produced by fltpage
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{adja-page}{\hrulefill\\#1 #2 \emph{(previous page)}}

%...

\begin{document}

%...

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{<YOUR FIGURE>}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=adja-page}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \caption{<YOUR CAPTION>}
    \label{<FIGURE LABEL>}
\end{figure}

%...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to make sure stuff works for that environment. It is very a common one to use!

Comment: I get an error with this method if the caption text is long enough to require more than one page.  The specific error message is:  `! Dimension too large.
\caption@slc ...ke {#1}{#2}}\ifdim \wd \@tempboxa   ...    >\captionwidth \endgroup \...`.  Compilation was attempted with pdflatex (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19).

Answer (score 2):

If you need two pages, e.g., figure on one page and a caption on the next, this works:

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{turtle.pdf}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\caption{
   \label{turtle}
Here is a turtle.
}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: How will this allow the caption to span multiple pages, as in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I managed it in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{adja-page}{\hrulefill\\#1 #2 \emph{(previous page)}}
%
\begin{figure} [b!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.png}
    \caption[]{\textit{(see next page)}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure} [t!]
    \captionsetup{labelformat=adja-page}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \caption[Figure]{Description}
    \label{<FIGURE LABEL>}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```