# Caption of figure on multiple pages using PhDThesisPSnPDF class

Tags: captions

I am writing my thesis using PhDThesisPSnPDF class.
I need to make large caption of a figure to span over multiple pages. For most document classes package capt-of can be used:
[How do I make figure captions span multiple pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49858/how-do-i-make-figure-captions-span-multiple-pages)

However, this approach does not work in PhDThesisPSnPDF class. In PhDThesisPSnPDF \captionof instead of moving only the part of caption which does not fit on a current page, the entire caption is moved to a next page.

Are there any other options how to do this? 
Or is there a way to make capt-of work in the PhDThesisPSnPDF class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you be more precise about what you tried and give a pointer to the class?

Comment: On a site note and off-topic: I am not entirely sure whether having a caption spanning multiple pages is a good idea anyway.I think maybe it is easier to have a shorter caption which fits on one page, then reference the figure in the text and write the long description where you reference it.

Comment: Egrer, I tried to use \captionof{figure}{} with caption package, instead of putting an image into the figure environment. This worked fine in book, article and report classes, but does not work in PhDThesisPSnPDF class. In PhDThesisPSnPDF \captionof instead of moving only the part of caption which does not fit on a current page, the entire caption is moved to the next page.

Comment: Regarding details on the PhDThesisPSnPDF class, I am using this template https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template

Comment: Are you studying at this university and specific department?

Comment: I just checked, it doesn't work with book either.