# How to get figure caption to span multiple pages, without having to switch everything to capt-of?

Tags: floats, captions

I have found several questions on TeX.SE and elsewhere about making figure captions span multiple pages (e.g., [How do I make figure captions span multiple pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49858/how-do-i-make-figure-captions-span-multiple-pages)).
I gather that the `caption` package puts the caption in unbreakable boxes.

Some answers recommend the use of the `capt-of` package. `capt-of` seems to work fine, but breaks `caption` instances. So it seems that using `capt-of` to enable long figure captions would require me to switch every single caption in my paper to `capt-of`, which is a burden and seems to eliminate the benefits of floating figures.

Here's a MWE (also on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/12004270zvtyphxfbtxw)) with a figure with short `caption` and a figure with a long `captionof`. **I would like to be able to have both `\usepackage{capt-of}`
 and `\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` enabled**, and still have my long caption span multiple pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

% I can't have both caption and capt-of enabled.

% Caption alone doesn't let long captions span multiple pages.    
\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

% Capt-of alone would require me to reformat many figures.
\usepackage{capt-of}

% But enabling both breaks capt-of's ability to span captions across pages.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1]

% I have many figures that are formatted like this.
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\caption[Short caption]{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]

% This seems to be the best way to get long captions to span multiple pages, while being styled like the above figure.
\begin{centering}
\sffamily
   \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.75\textheight}
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\lipsum[1-4]}
   \label{figure}
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, some way to easily allow `caption`s to span pages without having to re-format would be great.

Comment: The `caption` package also defines `\captionof{...}{...}`, so you don't need `capt-of` for that when you already load `caption`. And please add MWEs to the question rather than Overleaf.

Comment: But `caption` alone doesn't allow captions to span multiple pages. I'll add the MWE now.

Comment: latex floats are boxes and can never span multiple pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's why I am willing to instead use non-floating `captionof` for my figures with very long captions. But if I use that alone, my `caption` formatting (small, sans-serif) is lost.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry for the misunderstanding. (By the way, only you who owns the post is notified of all comments, if you want to notify other commenters, you need to write an at-sign followed by the username, e.g. @DavidCarlisle. Tab-completion of usernames is available.)

Comment: unrelated but `\begin{figure}[h!]` is usually wrong, latex will warn and change it to `[!ht]` but `[htp]` would be better.

Comment: While splitting works with the original caption command it imho won't work with the caption command from the caption package: it puts the caption inside a box. If you really want such long captions you will have to define your own command.

Comment: I would also be happy if there was a styling workaround to just use capt-of, and find a way to make all of my preexisting captions small and sans-serif.

Comment: Scratching my head here. A caption longer than a page? Just make a section/subsection out of it. The caption would be short: `\caption{What i was writing about for the last three pages}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: It shouldn't be too hard to imagine. I'm writing a dissertation with strict formatting guidelines (i.e., huge margins), have a figure with many subplots that I'd like to be big and readable, and would like a detailed caption. But given the difficulty of getting this done, I do think I'm just going to adjust my caption length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `capt-of` package which is just one line and the same definition is in `caption` however caption boxes the caption text so if you want it to break you need to unbox it:

```
\documentclass{article}

% I can't have both caption and capt-of enabled.

% Caption alone doesn't let long captions span multiple pages.    
\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1]

% I have many figures that are formatted like this.
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\caption[Short caption]{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]

% This seems to be the best way to get long captions to span multiple pages, while being styled like the above figure.
\begin{center}

   \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.75\textheight}

\bigskip
\setbox0\vbox{\makeatletter
\let\caption@rule\relax
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\lipsum[1-4]}
\global\skip1\lastskip\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}
\unvbox0
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\unvbox1
\vskip\skip1



\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But your second caption now does not span multiple pages. You need to have `\usepackage{capt-of}` for that.

Comment: @WillAdler capt-of package is is exactly one line of code and doesn't have anything that isn't already in the caption package? I'll see if I can re-create what you describe...

Comment: @WillAdler updated answer with breaking caption

Comment: Weirdly, any of `\usepackage{xcolor}`, `\usepackage{color}`and `\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperef}` seem to break this solution. But I'll accept anyway! Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this hack is needed. As far as I can see `\captionsetup{rule=false,parbox=none}\captionof{figure}[...]{...}` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `caption` package puts the caption content inside a `\parbox` since this is needed for supporting some `caption` package options (margins etc.). But this can be changed with `\captionsetup{parbox=...}`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1]

% I have many figures that are formatted like this.
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\caption[Short caption]{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]

% This seems to be the best way to get long captions to span multiple pages, while being styled like the above figure.
\begin{centering}
\sffamily
   \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.75\textheight}
\captionsetup{parbox=none}% don't put this caption into a \parbox
\captionof{figure}[short caption]{\lipsum[1-4]}
   \label{figure}
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```