# Hyperref not working with custom figure environment spanning multiple pages

Tags: hyperref, captions

I would like to use the `hyperref` package to highlight the citations and urls in blue in the text (`\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}`), as well as later using `hyperref` to link Figure citations to the corresponding figure page.

However, I use a custom figure environment to handle captions spanning multiple pages in case of large figures/large captions.

When I set the `hyperref package`, the captions that spanned multiple pages raise a warning

> Package caption warning: The option 'hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption.

How can I concile large caption spanning multiple pages with package `hyperref`?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pts,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./fig/}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/chap2-workflow.pdf}
\bigskip
\setbox0\vbox{\makeatletter
\let\caption@rule\relax
\captionof{figure}[My Figure Title.]{Very very large caption}
\global\skip1\lastskip\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}
\unvbox0
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\unvbox1
\vskip\skip1
\label{workflow1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try using \capstart from the hypcap package.

Answer (score 1):

The warning continues in the log with

> See the caption package documentation for explanation.

And if search there for hypcap you will end in the section `6.5 hyperref` which describes your options. One for example is to use `\captionsetup` and `\caption` instead of `\captionof` outside of a real float environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[font={small,sf}, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[My Figure Title.]{Very very large caption}
\label{workflow1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution isn't that trivial. Following your suggestion, the whole caption lies appart from the figure, on the next page, although it could have begun just below the figure. Your solution does not allow the caption to span on multiple pages.

Comment: Your example didn't compile and doesn't have a long caption. But `\captionof{figure}` instead of \caption  should work too. For other options check the documentation.

Comment: The issue has been raised in @WillAdler 's comments [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399698/how-to-get-figure-caption-to-span-multiple-pages-without-having-to-switch-every) but nobody could find a way to bypass this behavior.

Comment: The other question has nothing to do with the hyperref anchor but only with the question if caption can break over a page or not.