# How shoud I manage captions and sub captions with float and non float items?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

I am currently writing my PhD thesis and I am using [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig) to put some figures or tables on the left page. So, I have two kinds of figures, some are in a float, some are not.
In both cases, I often use sub floats (with subfigure package for floats, and \captionof{subfigure} for left pages figures).

The issue is about sub caption labelling. For example, I have a left page figure with two subfigures, let's say 1.A and 1.B.

If I put a regular floating figure after this and let's say 2 subs, I get 2.C and 2.D like if figure number is correctly increased and subfigure letter is continuous.

My question is the following:

How do you "strongly" delimit figures and subfigures so that referencing is correct ?

I tried to define a new environment, to move labels and captions commands, etc. without success.
What is the general way to proceed ?

EDIT : 
Here is my general syntax

for left page figures I use the command provided in the link above :

```
\addfig{
*subfigure contents*
\captionof{subfigure}
\label{subfigure}

*subfigure contents*
\captionof{subfigure}
\label{subfigure}
}
```

and then a floating one

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[title]{
*subfigure contents*
\label{subfigure}
}
\subfloat[title]{
*subfigure contents*
\label{subfigure}
\end{figure}.
```

Subfigures labels are continued between the two figures.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: HelloYes I was working on it, but I cannot reproduce the error outside my thesis. No labelling issues with the MWE I've been making.

Comment: the only way in standard latex is to put a `\clearpage` before and after your non-floating figure to stop floats floating past it and get out of sequence. A slightly less intrusive variant is the `\FloatBarrier` command from the `placeins` package which essentially just adds `\clearpage` if it is needed because there are pending floats, otherwise the forced page break is avoided.

Comment: My previous comment was about the floats themselves getting out of sequence.If you are getting 2.C it means that you are not resetting the subfigure counter when figure counter is incremented (which should be automatic) would need to see the example code

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. I'm gonna try \FloatBarrier, but I don't think this will help. I edited my post to put in code I use.

Comment: Dear David, putting \clearpage before and after does not change subfigures labelling.

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

In the document:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \addfig{
        *subfigure contents*
        \captionof{subfigure}
        \label{subfigure}

        *subfigure contents*
        \captionof{subfigure}
        \label{subfigure}
    }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hello Thiago, I don't get it. Could you add a word to explain ?

Comment: The `float` package allows the insertion of a figure exactly where it is placed using `[H]`, so instead of directly inserting pictures like a "character" (without `figure` environment), fits it into the `figure` environment giving continuity to the reference counters.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I can't use it. When I place figures on left pages, they can NOT be included in a floating environment. But your idea is very good and I learned the use of 'H' that could be useful elsewhere.

Comment: May I ask you why not?

Comment: because the \addfig command defined in the link I posted in my first post keeps its content until the next left page, and its function does not work with a float inside.

Comment: maybe this can help:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/figures-in-odd-pages-text-in-even-pages-if-no-figures-then-odd-even-pages-i

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55653/placing-figure-on-an-even-odd-page