# How to force LaTeX to print a table in an even-numbered page

Tags: tables, page-numbering

Is there a way that I can force a table to be printed in an even-numbered page? One thing that comes to mind is to print a blank page before it if the table happens to be in an odd page but this makes the document very unprofessional and discontinuous.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline test11 &  test12\\ 
    \hline  test21&  test22\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=oddpage

Comment: @@Papiro: after knowing whether I am in the odd or even page, how should I manage the text before and after the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing figure on an even/odd page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55653)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example using the information from [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ifthen,changepage,afterpage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\mytable}{% sample table
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline  test11&  test12\\ 
    \hline  test21&  test22\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
 }
\begin{document}       
\lipsum[1-10]

\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage    % if currently on an odd-numbered page, defer execution
    \afterpage{ \mytable }
\else         % else, insert table immediately
    \mytable
\fi

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```