# longtable: alternating column names/splitting wide table across pages

Tags: longtable, threeparttable

Need to split some wide tables across multiple pages using longtable.  The code below provides an example of what I’m trying to do.  Some of the column names need to vary by page.  Specifically, columns 4-7 should be labelled “IB”, “IIA”, “II”, and “ ” on odd numbered pages of the table and “IIB”, “IIIA”, “Other”, and “Overall” on even numbered pages.  (Note though that the table itself could start on an odd or an even numbered page in a document.)

The code below produces correct output on pages 1, 2, and 4, but not on page 3. There, columns 4-7 read “IIB”, “IIIA”, “Other”, and “Overall” when they should say “IB”, “IIA”, “II”, and “ ”.  Imagine there’s some way to fix this, but it seems well beyond my current abilities. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%% Margins %%

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}

%%%% Packages %%%%

\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[pdfview=Fit]{hyperref}

%%%% Table Captions %%%%

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{period-newline}{. } 
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=period-newline,aboveskip=3pt}

\begin{document}

{
\scriptsize
\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
  \item[] 
    A footnote I might want to add to the bottom of each page
    at a later date.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}[l]{ c c p{3.5in} *{4}{>{\centering}m{0.75in}} } 
  \caption[Treatment Regimens by Line]{Treatment Regimens by Line and Regimen} \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
   &    &         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Disease Substage} &         \\ \cmidrule(l){4-6}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & IB  & IIA  & II             &         \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Treatment Regimens by Line and Regimen (Continued)}   \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
   &    &         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Disease Substage} &         \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & IIB & IIIA & Other          & Overall \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{7}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
   \insertTableNotes
\endfoot
   \hline
   \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

%%%% Pages 1 and 2 %%%%

\addlinespace
1 & 1 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace

  & 2 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace 

  & 3 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace 

  & 4 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace 

2 & 1 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace[3pt]

\newpage

\addlinespace
1 & 1 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace

  & 2 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

  & 3 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

  & 4 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

2 & 1 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace[3pt]

\newpage

%%%% Pages 3 and 4 %%%%

\addlinespace 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace  

  & 2 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace[3pt]

\newpage

\addlinespace 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace  

  & 2 & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Lengthy text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace[3pt] 

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While it doesn't use `longtable`, and approach like this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108494/how-can-i-create-a-table-that-spans-across-the-width-of-two-vertical-and-opposi/131544#131544 might be adapted.

Comment: Thanks Steven. It might be possible to adapt the approach in the link above. It's not clear to me that that's the case though. For example, I'd like to be able to have a footnote that appears repeatedly on each page of the table. My understanding is that this requires the use of threeparttablex or something along those lines. So even if I could adapt this code, it occurs to me that I might then need to know how to write something complicated that would allow me to get the footnotes the way I need them. Am hoping there is some way to do it using longtable/threeparttablex.

Comment: I fully understand the desire to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with. Not pretty, but easy to understand and it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%% Margins %%

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}

%%%% Packages %%%%

\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[pdfview=Fit]{hyperref}

%%%% Table Captions %%%%

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{period-newline}{. } 
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=period-newline,aboveskip=3pt}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

{
\scriptsize
\begin{landscape}

%%%% Pages 1 and 2 %%%%

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[] 
    A footnote I might want to add to the bottom of each page
    at a later date.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}[l]{ c c p{3.45in} *{3}{>{\centering}m{0.88in}} } 
  \caption[Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage]{Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage} \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
        &         &        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Disease Stage}    \\ \cmidrule(l){4-5}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & I   & II    &                       \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage (Continued)}    \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
        &         &        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Disease Stage}   \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & III & Other & Overall               \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
   %\insertTableNotes
\endfoot
   \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
   %\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

\addlinespace

1 & 1 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ \addlinespace

  & 2 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ \addlinespace 

  & 3 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ \addlinespace 

  & 4 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ \addlinespace 

2 & 1 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &             \\ \addlinespace[3pt]

\newpage

\addlinespace
1 & 1 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace

  & 2 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

  & 3 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

  & 4 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace 

2 & 1 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace[3pt]

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

%%%% Pages 3 and 4 %%%%

\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
  \item[] 
    A footnote I might want to add to the bottom of each page
    at a later date.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}[l]{ c c p{3.45in} *{3}{>{\centering}m{0.88in}} } 
 \caption[]{Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage (Continued)}   \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
        &         &        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Disease Stage}  \\ \cmidrule(l){4-5}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & I   & II    &                     \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Treatment by Line, Regimen, and Disease Stage (Continued)}  \\ \hline \addlinespace[3pt]
        &         &        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Disease Stage} \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
   Line & Regimen & Agents & III & Other & Overall             \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
%\insertTableNotes
\endfoot
   \hline
   %\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

\addlinespace 
2 $\ldots$ & 1 $\ldots$ & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace  

  & 2 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) &              \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
$\ldots$ \\

\newpage

\addlinespace 
2 $\ldots$ & 1 $\ldots$ & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace  

  & 2 & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ 
  &   & Text description of regimen $\ldots$ & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) & xxx/xxx (xx.x\%) \\ \addlinespace[3pt] 
$\ldots$ \\

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
}

\end{document}
```