# doublepagepicture is messing up my text

Tags: floats

I am very new to LaTeX's usage. I have a very big picture which takes about two pages. I found out how to do it on the following link [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right) It has almost worked with some few exceptions.

As a consequence this has changed my entire text after the figure to Latin and I am not able to get it back to English.

In addition, the image is not appearing where I want it to appear but rather 8 pages after the wished position.

`\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` are not working

here is how I called the image

```
 \lipsum
 \lipsum
 \twopagepicture{t}{l}{img/myimage.jpeg}{Test}
 \lipsum
 \lipsum
```

Below is the code in the preambles

```
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.99}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.99}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.01}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\twopagepicture}[4]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
    \expandafter\@firstofone
\else
    \expandafter\afterpage
\fi
{\afterpage{%
\if #1t%
    \if #2p%

        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}%
    \fi
\fi

\begin{figure}[#1]
    \if #2p%
        \if #1t%
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \if #1b%
        \caption{#4}%
    \fi
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \if #2p\relax
        \let\mywidth\paperwidth
        \hskip-\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin\relax
    \else
        \let\mywidth\linewidth
    \fi
    \adjustbox{trim=0 0 {.5\width} 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
    \if #1b\else
        \caption{#4}%
    \fi
    \if #2p%
        \if #1b%
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr\paperheight-\textheight-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-  \headheight-\headsep\relax}%
        \fi
    \fi
\end{figure}%

\begin{figure}[#1]
    \if #2p%
        \if #1t%
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \if #2p%
        \let\mywidth\paperwidth
        \hskip-\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin\relax
    \else
        \let\mywidth\linewidth
    \fi
    \adjustbox{trim={.5\width} 0 0 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
    \if #2p%
        \if #1b%
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr\paperheight-\textheight-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep\relax}%
        \fi
    \fi
\end{figure}%
}}%

}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
```

What could I do to solve these two big problems? Does anyone have any idea on what is going wrong? I want to add that I'm viewing the result in pdf

Comment: "this has changed my entire text after the figure to latin" - Is it possible that you might be mistaken and in fact this is due to `\lipsum`? Why don't you try `\twopagepicture{t}{l}{img/myimage.jpeg}{Test}` without lipsum preceding and following it? (`\lipsum` generates a bunch of latin text, as 'filler'.)

Comment: @srao thanks a lot. the latin text problem has been solved.        in addition the position problem was also solved with \cleardoublepage. you made my day, unfortunately I am not able to give you some rate

Comment: Glad it helped. I have posted the comment as an answer below, you may 'accept' it if it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\lipsum` generates a bunch of latin text, as 'filler'. If you remove all instances of this and just type the following alone

```
 \twopagepicture{t}{l}{img/myimage.jpeg}{Test}
```

the issue is solved.