# Need to insert a page in A3 format in a A4 format document

Tags: paper-size

There are a few replies to a similar question, but my problem is that it is my thesis and I cannot change the header and footer.

It is also to be in annex to the thesis, landscape mode and it should be to include high resolution pages.

Is it possible to do that?

Kind regards,

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I assume that the A3-sized pages are created in a separate LaTeX program. Have you looked into the `pdfpages` package? It lets users insert externally-created single-page or multi-page pdf documents at various places in a LaTeX document.

Comment: @MadyYuvi How should geometry help to include a PDF?

Comment: @TeXnician I guess @MadyYuvi tries to put a double page of A3 size in an A4 document in the same TeX-document, that's why he/she/it/Apache helicopter recommends the `geometry` package.

Comment: I thought that to change the A3 layout to A4 layout, that's why I suggested that, now I deleted my comment...

Comment: what you need is not clear, what does mean `in annex...landscape`

Comment: @touhami I have a model pre made to follow in Latex. It has headers and footers, this A3 I need it to be in the annex part, but this part is just the same as a normal text, instead of chapter it is annex.
For the landscape, is just that, I would like to have the page in landscape in A3, and then manually folded into an A4 shape when printed.

Comment: please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right

Comment: @touhami thank you but that it's not what I am searching for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the main document (in A4) and add an empty page where the A3 page should be (\newpage). Then create another .tex file that uses pdfpages to include all the pages of the A4 document up to the empty page, then include only the A3 page from the second document, and finally the rest of the main document. This way page numbers are correct and in the PDF there will be all pages but the one in A4.

Comment: Hello, thank you. The main document is in fact already produced in A4 format. When you say second document, do you mean an A3 formated .tex document?
Nevertheless I will take a look at `pdfpages` package.

Comment: can I import the PDF file directly, instead of creating a new file? The things I am trying to import are maps, in A3 and A1 format. I can produce those in PDF externally. The only concern I have, is that it has to maintain the page formatting, both header, footer and page number. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, instead of a master document you can import it directly into the main document.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Although I lost the header and footer. But there in no need for that. Your solution worked.