# insert wide image at top and bottom page (book)

Tags: graphics, books, wide-image

I work on a Latex book template, and at the moment, I try to include a wide image on the top of a page, and another one on its bottom.
The images should ignore the margin, and text should not overlap the images.

My first try result in something like this:

[image]

Code: 
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,openany]{book}

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\rpgarttop}[1]{%
    \begin{figure*}[!t]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % need to get the image dimension here
    %\rule{image width}{image height}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{figure*}%
}

\newcommand*{\rpgartbottom}[1]{%
    \begin{figure*}[!t]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south] at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure*}%

}


\begin{document}

\rpgarttop{art-top}
\rpgartbottom{art-bottom}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-15]


\end{document}
```

As you can see, the margin are ignored, but the text overlap the images.

If one of you have any idea to solve this issue, it will be super nice !

Also, here is a link to the entire project : https://github.com/Krozark/RPG-LaTeX-Template

---

Edit 1 : Add comment for image dimension

Comment: Welcome! You haven't left any room for them. `overlay` means it takes no space. So the text just starts where it normally would and ends where it normally would. You need to adjust your top margin and height of the text block. (Using `geometry` would be the easiest way. Then you can just set the `top` and `bottom` margins as you need.)

Comment: Thanks @cfr! But is there a way to get the image dimention from latex ? This way, I could calculate the margin that I have to add, as not all the page will have a top and/or bottom image, and those images will also change from pages to pages.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes you can get the information directly. Depends a bit on engine, file type etc. Failing that, you can put it into a box and measure the box before typesetting it. This is probably the most flexible way, since it doesn't matter what is in the box.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a way to have the correct behavior:
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,openany]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\rpghmargin}
\newcommand*{\pagepicture}[2]{%
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
        \setlength{\rpghmargin}{\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+32pt \relax}
    \else
        \setlength{\rpghmargin}{\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin-25pt \relax}

    \fi
    \begin{figure*}[#1!]
        \centering
        \if #1t
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep \relax}
        \fi

         \makebox[\paperwidth][l]{
            \hskip-\rpghmargin \relax
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#2}
        }
        \if #1b
            \vspace*{-\dimexpr\paperheight-\textheight-1in+12pt-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep\relax}
        \fi

    \end{figure*}
}


\begin{document}

\pagepicture{t}{art-top}
\pagepicture{b}{art-bottom}

\lipsum 
\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

The links that help me :

- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=5552&sid=e81778c7456a67b5e737367c7ef9643e#p5552
- [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right)